# Python's beautifulsoup scraper stops working correctly after a couple of pages

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping my local site for apartments rental/buying and write them into excel file. The amount of advertisments on the site is around 9500 but my scraper stops working correctly after around 1000 and then apparently scrapes only one add per page.

I added the

```
prink(link)
```

to the loop, so it shows me which page it is currently working on.

here's the result:

```
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=34
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=34
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=34
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=34
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=34
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=34
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=35
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=36
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=37
https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?strona=38
```

After page 34 it only loads one add per page.

I tried changing the range to 50,100 / 100,150 etc but it was behaving similarly, after around 25-30 pages it was behaving like above.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})

tytuly = []
lokalizacje = []
Ceny = []
Ceny_m = []
Powierzchnie = []
L_pokoi = []
Pietra = []
rok_budowy = []

strona = 0
numer = 0
for strona in range(0,50):
    strona +=1
    link = 'https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-rynek-pierwotny/?' + 'strona=' + str(strona)
    r = get(link, headers = headers)
    zupa = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    ogloszenia= zupa.find_all('div', class_="list__item")
    print(link)
    for ogl in ogloszenia:
        try:
            tytul = ogl.find_all('h2', class_ ="list__item__content__title")[0].text
        except IndexError:
            tytul = ''
        try:
            powierzchnia = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[0].text
        except IndexError:
            powierzchnia = ''
        try:    
            liczba_pok = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[1].text
        except IndexError:
            liczba_pok = ''
        try:
            pietro = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[2].text
        except IndexError:
            pietro = ''
        try:
            if pietro == '':
                rok = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[2].text
            else:
                rok = ogl.find_all('p', class_ ="list__item__details__icons__element__desc")[3].text 
        except IndexError:
            rok = ''    
        try:
            lokalizacja = ogl.find_all('p', class_ = "list__item__content__subtitle")[0].text
        except IndexError:
            lokalizacja = ''
        try:
            cena = ogl.find_all('p', class_ = "list__item__price__value")[0].text
        except IndexError:
            cena = ''
        try:
            cena_m = ogl.find_all('p', class_ = "list__item__details__info details--info--price")[0].text
        except IndexError:
            cena_m = ''

        print(link)
        sys.getsizeof(tytuly)
        tytuly.append(tytul)
        lokalizacje.append(lokalizacja)
        Ceny.append(cena)
        Ceny_m.append(cena_m) 
        Powierzchnie.append(powierzchnia)  
        Pietra.append(pietro)
        L_pokoi.append(liczba_pok)
        rok_budowy.append(rok)

        kolumny = ["Tytul","Lokalizacja","Cena","Cena za metr","Powierzchnia","Pietro","Liczba pokoi","Rok budowy"]
zrzut = pd.DataFrame({"Tytul": tytuly,
                     "Lokalizacja": lokalizacje,
                     "Cena": Ceny,
                     "Cena za metr": Ceny_m,
                     "Powierzchnia": Powierzchnie,
                     "Pietro": Pietra,
                     "Liczba pokoi": L_pokoi,
                     "Rok budowy": rok_budowy})[kolumny]



zrzut.to_excel('rynek_pierwotnyy.xls')
```

My guess is that the lists are getting overloaded and that's why it's behaving like this. I think maybe clearing the lists and exporting to excel after each loop would help? But if I do it like this I would have to append the excel file.

Comment: This might be a limitation set by the website

Comment: Probably it was, adding the sleep function helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code in range 0-50 and 0-100 it works without your problem. Maybe the problem is about the internet or page loading. Please try to use time.sleep(). Hope it help you.

Comment: Hey, I made the code sleep for two second after every page and it worked. I was able to scrape 920 pages of another category. Maybe it was a site limitation as mentioned in the comment above. Thanks a lot!